# Removing product attributes from the order email

Tags: email-templates

I have 3 attributes assigned to each product (size, color, logo).  All of my products are configurable products thus each SKU contains the size, color, and logo along with the actual SKU for the product (they were auto-generated during the creation process).  What I would like to show on the order email is just the product name, SKU, Qty, and subtotal and can not figure out how to remove the attributes from being displayed under each product ordered.  The issue for my client is typically there are multiple products purchased on each order and when printing the order via email it can get quite long. Below is what is shown today on the email under Item (I used '...' to simulate spaces):

**Item**..............................**SKU**.....................................**Qty**.................**Subtotal**

Mens Shirt.....................X123-Blue-Small-Logo1.......1.......................$20.00

***Color***

Blue

***Size***

Small

***Logo***

Logo1

What I would like to show is only the item name and NOT each attribute underneath.  Essentially it would look something like the below (I added '...' to simulate spaces):

**Item**.....................**SKU**...............................................**QTY**.................**Subtotal**

Mens Shirt............X123-Blue-Small-Logo1..................1.......................$20.00

Womans Shirt......X456-Blue-Medium-Logo2...............2.......................$30.00

Has anyone ran into this before and know where I can go to 'hide' the attributes from being shown on the order email.  I have been to many forums looking at the sales.xml and items.phtml files, however I have not yet found the exact place where the attributes are being called and displayed on the order email.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

it is so simple.
Goto

```
app/design/frontend/your Package/your template/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml hav
```

Here you have find the code

```
<?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
<dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
    <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
    <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
        <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
    </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
<?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
    <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
```

Just remove it. it will works